# Problemas com Serialize Delphi - tkPointer

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey

Bom dia, estou com um problema ao tentar usar a função:

```
TJson.ObjectToJsonString( Pedido )
```

Da Unit REST.Json

O objeto que estou tentando converter para Json é o seguinte:

```
unit class_regjson;

interface

uses
   Classes;

type

   TItemConsultaCep = class(TCollectionItem)
   private
     FLogradouro  : String;
     FComplemento : String;
     FBairro      : String;
     FCidade      : String;
     FUF          : String;
     FUnidade     : String;
   published
     property LOGRADOURO  : String  read FLogradouro   write FLogradouro;
     property COMPLEMENTO : String  read FComplemento  write FComplemento;
     property BAIRRO      : String  read FBairro       write FBairro;
     property CIDADE      : String  read FCidade       write FCidade;
     property UF          : String  read FUF           write FUF;
     property UNIDADE     : String  read FUnidade      write FUnidade;
   end;

   TConsultaCep = class(TCollection)
   private
      function GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TItemConsultaCep;
   public
      count: Integer;
      function Add: TItemConsultaCep;
      property Item[Index: Integer]: TItemConsultaCep read GetItem;
      function Last: TItemConsultaCep;
   end;

   TItemEndereco = class(TCollectionItem)
   private
      FReferencia  : String;
      FComplemento : String;
      FBairro      : String;
      FCidade      : String;
      FNumero      : Integer;
      FCep         : String;
      FEndereco    : String;
      FEstado      : String;
      FConsultaCep : TConsultaCep;
   published
      property REFERENCIA   : String       read FReferencia  write FReferencia;
      property COMPLEMENTO  : String       read FComplemento write FComplemento;
      property BAIRRO       : String       read FBairro      write FBairro;
      property CIDADE       : String       read FCidade      write FCidade;
      property NUMERO       : Integer      read FNumero      write FNumero;
      property CEP          : String       read FCep         write FCep;
      property ENDERECO     : String       read FEndereco    write FEndereco;
      property ESTADO       : String       read FEstado      write FEstado;
      property CONSULTA_CEP : TConsultaCep read FConsultaCep write FConsultaCep;
   end;

   TEndereco = class(TCollection)
   private
      function GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TItemEndereco;
   public
      count : Integer;
      function Add: TItemEndereco;
      property Item[Index: Integer]: TItemEndereco read GetItem;
      function Last: TItemEndereco;
   end;

   TPedido = class(TPersistent)
   private
      FCodWeb     : Integer;
      FReferencia : String;
      FStatus     : Integer;
      FPheTipo    : String;
      FPheMin     : Integer;
      FPheHora    : String;

      FEndereco   : TEndereco;
   public
      procedure Clear;
      procedure Assign (APersistent: TPersistent) ; override;
   published
      property CODIGO_WEB : Integer     read FCodWeb      write FCodWeb;
      property REFERENCIA : String      read FReferencia  write FReferencia;
      property STATUS     : Integer     read FStatus      write FStatus;
      property PHE_TIPO   : String      read FPheTipo     write FPheTipo;
      property PHE_MIN    : Integer     read FPheMin      write FPheMin;
      property PHE_HOR    : String      read FPheHora     write FPheHora;
      property ENDERECO   : TEndereco   read FEndereco    write FEndereco;
   end;

implementation

   procedure TPedido.Assign(APersistent: TPersistent) ;
   begin
      if APersistent is TPedido then
      begin
         CODIGO_WEB := TPedido(APersistent).CODIGO_WEB;
         REFERENCIA := TPedido(APersistent).REFERENCIA;
         STATUS     := TPedido(APersistent).STATUS;
         PHE_TIPO   := TPedido(APersistent).PHE_TIPO;
         PHE_MIN    := TPedido(APersistent).PHE_MIN;
         PHE_HOR    := TPedido(APersistent).PHE_HOR;
         ENDERECO   := TPedido(APersistent).ENDERECO;
      end
      else
         inherited Assign (APersistent);
   end;

   procedure TPedido.Clear;
   begin
      CODIGO_WEB := 0;
      REFERENCIA := '';
      STATUS     := 0;
      PHE_TIPO   := '';
      PHE_MIN    := 0;
      PHE_HOR    := '';
      ENDERECO   := TEndereco.Create(TItemEndereco);
   end;

   function TEndereco.Add: TItemEndereco;
   var
      itemEndereco: TItemEndereco;
   begin
      itemEndereco := inherited Add as TItemEndereco;
      count := count + 1;
      itemEndereco.CONSULTA_CEP := TConsultaCep.Create(TItemConsultaCep);
      Result := itemEndereco;
   end;

   function TEndereco.GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TItemEndereco;
   begin
     Result := inherited Items[AIndex] as TItemEndereco;
   end;

   function TEndereco.Last: TItemEndereco;
   begin
     Result := Item[Count - 1];
   end;

   function TConsultaCep.Add: TItemConsultaCep;
   begin
      count := count + 1;
      Result := inherited Add as TItemConsultaCep;
   end;

   function TConsultaCep.GetItem(AIndex: Integer): TItemConsultaCep;
   begin
     Result := inherited Items[AIndex] as TItemConsultaCep;
   end;

   function TConsultaCep.Last: TItemConsultaCep;
   begin
     Result := Item[Count - 1];
   end;

end.
```

Quando passa pela linha de conversão eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Internal: tkPointer is not currently supported

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**INFORMAÇÕES**
Delphi 10.3

**PREENCHIMENTO DO OBJETO**

```
  Pedido := TPedido.Create;

  try

     Pedido.Clear;

     Pedido.CODIGO_WEB := 515;
     Pedido.REFERENCIA := '3917635439695030';
     Pedido.STATUS     := 0;
     Pedido.PHE_TIPO   := '';
     Pedido.PHE_MIN    := 0;
     Pedido.PHE_HOR    := '';

     Pedido.ENDERECO.Add;
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.REFERENCIA  := '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.COMPLEMENTO := '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.BAIRRO      := 'OUTROS';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.NUMERO      := 100;
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CEP         := '12345-678';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.ENDERECO    := 'R TESTE';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.ESTADO      := 'AC';

     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Add;
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.LOGRADOURO  :=  '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.COMPLEMENTO :=  '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.BAIRRO      :=  '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.CIDADE      :=  '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.UF          :=  '';
     Pedido.ENDERECO.Last.CONSULTA_CEP.Last.UNIDADE     :=  '';

     //json := TJson


     Memo1.Lines.Text := TJson.ObjectToJsonString( Pedido );

  finally

     Pedido.Free;

  end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Troca sua propriedade ENDERECO, por TARRAY, adicione no constructor a criação do array, e no Destroy a limpeza dele